# generate range of numbers from 1 to N in Netezza

Tags: netezza

I was wondering if there is an option to simply generate a range of numbers from 1 to N in Netezza?

Let's say that N=5, then my result should be:

| N |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

select _v_vector_idx.idx where idx between 1 and 10;

Note: IDX range is 0-1023

Comment: Is there any option to increase range? For example to 5000? :)

Comment: /*
The table _V_VECTOR_IDX returns the numbers 0..1024.  We can just join the table to itself to generate 1M rows
*/
select val from
(select ((t1.idx * 1024) + t2.idx) as val from _v_vector_idx t1 cross join _v_vector_idx t2) as list_of_one_million_numbers
where val between 1 and 5000;