# SQL: Adding an ID Column to a Table

Tags: sql, database

I am working with Netezza SQL.

**I want to add an ID column to my tabl**e (e.g. row 1 -  id = 1, row 2 - id = 2, etc.) - each row should have a unique ID value.

Usually, this is not a problem. I just run the following code:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY column_name) AS id, column1, column2, column3
FROM your_table;
```

However, the above code assumes that there exists some column ("column_name") with no duplicates - if this column does contain duplicates, then the ID column will contain duplicates as well.

In a previous question ([SQL: Using CASE WHEN for Missing Rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75748541/sql-using-case-when-for-missing-rows)), I learned that Netezza contains a built-in table with integers from 0,1,2,3...n . This table is called `_v_vector_idx` and contains a single column (`IDX`) with these integers.

**My Question:** I am trying to learn how I can use this `_v_vector_idx` table to create ID's in my table - I had thought of doing this using an INNER JOIN, but I am not sure what column I would use for this join.

**Can someone please show me how to do this?**

Thanks!

**Note:** I found an indirect way to accomplish something similar

```
select *,cast(random()* 10000 as integer) as random_number from your_table
```

But apart from these being random ID's (not in ascending order from 0 onwards) - I have no way of guaranteeing that some of these random ID's were not coincidentally created twice.
I know that I can check this manually using a `DISTINCT` statement - but this is very time consuming and I was hoping for a more direct way.

Comment: Have you tried `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` or `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY 1)`?

Comment: error: row number must include order by specification

Comment: Read your question again and I see a mistake in your question: `ROW_NUMBER()` does not need the column to have no duplicates. It will generate unique ids even if `column_name` has duplicates. The window functions that generate the same id for duplicate values in `column_name` are `RANK()` and `DENSE_RANK()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most straightforward answer I could find:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS id, * FROM df
```

Answer (score 1):

This is untrue:

> `SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY column_name) AS id, column1, column2, column3 FROM your_table;` However, the above code assumes that
> there exists some column ("column_name") with no duplicates

The `ORDER BY` used in the `OVER` clause does NOT require any of the columns specified to be unique. Regardless of how non-unique the ordering is, `ROW_NUMBER` will not repeat an integer and every row gets a unique row number (unless you are also using `PARTITION BY`)

So I would contend that you simply do not need to use _v_vector_idx

> **ROW NUMBER**    Assigns a unique number to each row to which it is
> applied.  ROW_NUMBER() over(window_spec)
>
> https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/psfa/7.2.1?topic=reference-functions

Where a table of numbers can be useful is if looking for gaps in another table. Let's assume you have a serial number of some sort held in table1:

```
select numbertable.value
from numbertable
left join table1 on numbertable.value = table1.serialno
where table1.serialno IS NULL
and numbertable.value between 10000 and 99999
```

This would list the numbers not yet used by the table1.serialno in a given range

*nb: I'm not a Netezza user so I don't know the details of _v_vector_idx*

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you wanted to find duplicates with the row number () you can either use dense_rank() or partition by .

For Ex:-

```
select row_number() over (partition by Column_name order by id), * from table_name.
```

Or

```
select dense_rank() over (order by column_name),* from table_name.
```